# AWS EC2 Instance - tenancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multi-tenant, amazon-vpc

I understand that c3 is an instance type and c3.8x is a single host. If I request 2 c3.4x instances , it could be from the same host or it could be 1 half of one host and other half of a different host. In this case if my tenancy is dedicated ,then I will get both instances in the same host.

If I request c3.8x instance , irrespective of I asking for dedicated/default (shared) tenancy - It is always dedicated tenancy ?

Please correct me if I'm missing something here.

Comment: The usual default should be shared, but if I am not mistaken you can set a default per VPC instance.

Comment: Check the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/dedicated-instance.html

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is true only if you consider a C3 host to have 32 vCPUs. This seems to be correct, as confirmed by launching a dedicated c3.8xlarge which has only one slot available for instance launches. So yes, if you launch a c3.8xlarge instance, it will be the only instance on that physical host.

The only disadvantage to this approach that I can see is that if you will need to change the instance type to a smaller one in the future, you won't be able to change between default (shared) tenancy and dedicated tenancy; you will have to create an AMI and launch another instance with the desired tenancy. The opposite is also true (from dedicated to shared tenancy).